# How to get timezone offset from varchar in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, timezone-offset

I have a table that shows the timezone on a different db from where I copy some data through dblink. The value is written like this "America/Lima"

Is it possible to get the offset (-5) in oracle.

I need to use it in a view instead of the "INTERVAL '5' HOUR":

```
GROUP BY
        TRUNC(smoe_date - INTERVAL '5' HOUR)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`TZ_OFFSET`, I presume:

```
SQL> select tz_offset('America/Lima') from dual;

TZ_OFFS
-------
-05:00

SQL>
```

---

If you want the *number*, one option might be

```
SQL> select to_number(regexp_substr(tz_offset('America/Lima') , '-?\d+')) lima,
  2         to_number(regexp_substr(tz_offset('Europe/Berlin'), '-?\d+')) berlin
  3  from dual;

      LIMA     BERLIN
---------- ----------
        -5          2

SQL>
```

---

As of using it as result of a query from another table: you can't put the whole `SELECT` into the function; do it via join. For example (not very smart, but - illustrates what I meant to say). As you already have the `T_CONFIG` table, your query would start from line #2.

```
SQL> WITH t_config AS (SELECT 'TIME_ZONE' name, 'America/Lima' VALUE FROM DUAL)
  2    SELECT MAX (ename)
  3      FROM emp e CROSS JOIN t_config t
  4  GROUP BY TRUNC (
  5                hiredate
  6              - TO_NUMBER (REGEXP_SUBSTR (TZ_OFFSET (t.VALUE), '-?\d+')))
  7  /

MAX(ENAME)
----------
SMITH
BLAKE
TURNER
ADAMS
<snip>
```

Comment: Thank you for sharing this. 
Do you know how I could get that value in the view creation statement instead of the interval part?

I tried this but it does not work.
  GROUP BY
       TRUNC(some_date - to_number(regexp_substr(tz_offset(SELECT value FROM T_CONFIG WHERE NAME = 'TIME_ZONE') , '-?\d+')))

Comment: Note, result of `TZ_OFFSET()` relies on the current time. So, next week the result might be different. However, `America/Lima` doe not apply Daylight Saving Time, so it does not matter is this case.

Comment: You're welcome. I edited the answer and added some more info about how to use it in GROUP BY you mentioned. Have a look, please.

Comment: I'm glad if it helped.

Answer (score 1):

Using

```
GROUP BY some_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Lima'
```

should be more convenient, I think. Or maybe this one:

```
GROUP BY SYS_EXTRACT_UTC(some_date AT TIME ZONE 'America/Lima')
```

If you really like to get the timezone offset then I would rather suggest

```
EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_HOUR FROM FROM_TZ(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'America/Lima'))
EXTRACT(TIMEZONE_MINUTE FROM FROM_TZ(LOCALTIMESTAMP, 'America/Lima'))
```

instead of REGEXP